# Encountered fatal error executing job: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am upgrading my Spring boot/batch code from 1.4.0 to 2.7.2. The migration is done and most of the code is working. The code gets deployed to JBOSS7/wildfly.

I am getting an error while executing the job.

Error:

```
2022-08-30 08:16:04,280 INFO  [com.xyz.om.apm.batch.rest.ManualBatchTrigger] (default task-1) batchTrigger inside ManualBatchTrigger with date::: 20220714  ::::  triggered at::: Tue Aug 30 08:16:04 UTC 2022
2022-08-30 08:16:04,316 INFO  [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] (default task-1) Job: [SimpleJob: [name=baseApplicationDataExtractorJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{JobID=1661847364286, date=1657756800000}]

2022-08-30 08:16:04,370 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob] (default task-1) Encountered fatal error executing job: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97) [spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:880) [spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:906) [spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:307) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:174) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) [spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) [spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) [spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.updateStatus(AbstractJob.java:443) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:315) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at com.xyz.om.apm.batch.rest.ManualBatchTrigger.batchTrigger(ManualBatchTrigger.java:147) [classes:]
    at com.xyz.om.apm.batch.rest.ManualBatchTrigger$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5c65fdc.invoke(<generated>) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    

2022-08-30 08:16:04,382 INFO  [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] (default task-1) Job: [SimpleJob: [name=baseApplicationDataExtractorJob]] failed unexpectedly and fatally with the following parameters: [{JobID=1661847364286, date=1657756800000}]: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97) [spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:880) [spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:906) [spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:307) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:174) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) [spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) [spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) [spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_332]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) [spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:378) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar:4.3.6]
    at com.xyz.om.apm.batch.rest.ManualBatchTrigger.batchTrigger(ManualBatchTrigger.java:147) [classes:]
    at com.xyz.om.apm.batch.rest.ManualBatchTrigger$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5c65fdc.invoke(<generated>) [classes:]
```

I am not able to understand the issue here.

Code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class ManualBatchTrigger {
    
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManualBatchTrigger.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    @Autowired
    private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private Step baseApplicationDataExtractorStep;
    @Autowired
    private Job baseApplicationDataExtractorJob;
    @Autowired
    private FTSUtils ftsUtils;

@RequestMapping(value = "/triggerbatch/{date}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String batchTrigger(@PathVariable String date) throws ParseException {

        logger.info("batchTrigger inside ManualBatchTrigger with date::: " + date + "  ::::  triggered at::: " + new Date());

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        JobExecution execution = null;
        try {
            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .addDate("date", format.parse(date))
                    .toJobParameters();

            execution = jobLauncher.run(baseApplicationDataExtractorJob(baseApplicationDataExtractorStep), param);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("@@ Error in Manual Batch Trigger  2@@  :  ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        if(execution != null) {
            logger.info("execution != null");
            logger.info("Job finished with status :" + execution.getStatus());
            return execution.getStatus().toString();
        }           
        return "Job Failed!";
    }

    private Job baseApplicationDataExtractorJob(Step baseApplicationDataExtractorStep2) {
        return baseApplicationDataExtractorJob;
    }
```

**Error is at this line:**
I have googled the error 100 times but the error does not relate to any of solutions/queries asked.

```
execution = jobLauncher.run(baseApplicationDataExtractorJob(baseApplicationDataExtractorStep), param);
```

**FULL ERROR STACK: ** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p5didOTbMO3OE-qCAJYR-h9Cfrc79-TV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace of the error. It is not possible to understand the root cause from what you shared.

Comment: The issue is your statement requires that exactly one result is returned, but there are no results returned

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply:
Full error stack: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p5didOTbMO3OE-qCAJYR-h9Cfrc79-TV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The issue is not his statement, but one of spring-batch(org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:307)(

Comment: 4.3.6 source code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.3.6/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JdbcJobExecutionDao.java

Comment: It is the query: "SELECT VERSION FROM %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?"

Comment: Your update seems to have brought (spring-batch)data into an inconsistent state..

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have added the logs can you please have a look

Comment: @xerx593, Hi man, can you please help with the resolution.

Comment: Yes, something seems to be wrong with your Batch meta-data. The only way to help you in an efficient way is to share a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: i'd investigate the data(base), debug..., read upgrade guides (carefully!), and keep in mind, that spring-batch is not only a lib, but commonly also a (complete) database (schema).

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and the scenario also is same where we upgraded the Spring boot batch version from 2.1.7 to 2.4.0 @AmitChaudhary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really related to the update of SpringBoot.
The recommended of [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) is, at first, to migrate to the latest SpringBoot 1.5, and then to 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and so on.

This specific error I faced here and was related to internal beans, such as MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean and others which got deprecated and removed while you go through the versions of SpringBoot (and spring-core as well).

During the migration you can solve the problem by replacing the deprecated classes with the recommended ones in each deprecation note.

Answer (score -2):

In my case the problem was in spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false. After changing it to true it worked.

Comment: That shouldn't be the solution as you are now basically running without transactions. The fact that his "fixes" it means you have an issue somewhere with your transaction propagation/setup.